# What is the cardinality of a vanishing set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, finite-fields

In [Wiki's page on Chevalley–Warning theorem, under "Statement of the theorems"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorems), it's written that

> Chevalley–Warning theorem states that [...] the cardinality of the
> vanishing set of ${\displaystyle \{f_{j}\}_{j=1}^{r}}$ [...].

What does "the cardinality of the vanishing set of ${\displaystyle \{f_{j}\}_{j=1}^{r}}$" mean? (What is a vanishing set of polynomials? What is its cardinality?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is given by interpreting the multivariate polynomials $f_i(x_1,x_2,..x_m)$ as functions from $\mathbb{F}^m_q$ to $\mathbb{F}_q$, by the evaluation rule
\begin{equation}
(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...\alpha_m)\mapsto f_i(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_m)
\end{equation}

Where $\mathbb{F}^m_q$ here is just $m$ tuples of elements of $\mathbb{F}_q$.

So in this sense, we can talk about the tuples $(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_m)$ for which all these maps equal zero. This is our vanishing set, and its a subset of the (finite) set $\mathbb{F}^m_q$. The cardinality of this set is just the number of elements in this finite set.

As an example, take $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$. We have solutions $(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(0,1,1)$ and $(0,0,0)$, so we have $4$ solutions, so the solution set has cardinality $4$. This is an instance of the Chevalley warning theorem in action and would be good to work through the proof for to gain understanding.

Comment: Thank you. The first part helped me to understand better the notations. Regarding the last paragraph, what exactly do you mean by $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+z^2$? Is it a typo, and you meant $f(x, y, z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$? Also, why the 4 points are roots of $f$? Best regards

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, it should be $f(x,y,z)$. Those four points are the (only) ones for which when we evaluate them with that polynomial, we get zero. For instance, $(1,1,1)$ is not a root, since $f(1,1,1)=1^2+1^2+1^2=3=1\neq 0$. (Remembering 3=1 since we are working in $\mathbb{F}_2$.)

Comment: Thanks, I get it. Those points evaluate to $0$ since we work over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2$ (meaning that we apply $\text{mod } 2$ at the end)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, a *vanishing point* of a polynomial is a point in which the polynomial vanishes, i.e. equals $0$. Thus *vanishing point* is just a fancy name for what that also known as a "root" or a "solution" of the polynomial.

A *vanishing set* of a polynomial is therefore the polynomial's set of roots/solutions. Its cardinality is the number of roots.